# create Datadog monitor for ordered sequence of logs

Tags: datadog

i've recently had a bug in which there is a sequence of 3 logs that indicate this bug has occurred:
1.Entered GetCampaignDetailsForEdit for planId: 70138
2. AsyncExecution >> Create >> PlanId [70138] Create Campaign >> Started
3.SaveMarketingPlan() -> finished SaveMarketingActionPlan for planId 70138

I'd like to create a datadog monitor that would monitor if these 3 logs have all appeared in the exact order given above. couple of notes:

1. there might be a lot of other logs in between those 3. they are not consecutive.
2. the plan id must be identical for all 3 logs (in our example, the number 70138)
3. all the logs share an EventAttribute called TenantId which these 3 also must share.

if the 3 logs appear and the 3 notes are valid then i want my monitor to be triggered (slack channel notification, but that doesn't really matter).

how can i do this? how can i construct a search query that dictates the order of these 3 logs (as well as the 3 notes)?

thanks!